# SQL Filtering Query

Tags: sql

I have tried to figure out this query but need some help.

Edited the post, think I need to clear the problem.
I need to filter out the rows from T2 where Status for all rows belonging to BoxNums for a specific AcctId are set to 55 and Auto for that AcctId=Y

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do `SELECT DISTINCT` with `NOT EXISTS` .

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select accountid
from table t
group by accountid
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 55;
```

For all column you can do `JOIN` or use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select t2.*
from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t2.accountid = t1.accountid
where t1.auto = 'Y' and
      t2.status = 55 and
      not exists (select 1 from table t11 where t2.accountid = t11.accountid and t11.status <> t2.status);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But this also returns rows 4 and 6. I only want to see rows 1-3

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear. Do you mind taking another look? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the original data, use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.accountid = t2.accountid
where t1.auto = 'Y' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.accountid = t.accountid and t2.status <> 55
                 );
```

Comment: HI Gordon, thanks for the comment. I edited the post to be more clear. I'm still unclear how to check for all rows for the condition I want

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Its a straightforward `subquery` usage as give data of `T2` for a particular accountid which exists in `T2` and has a value `Y` in T1 as well.

```
      SELECT  Account_Id, 
      Box_num,Status FROM T2 WHERE 
       STATUS 
      =55 and account_id in (SELECT 
        account_id from T1 where auto='Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select b.* from 
t1 a,t2 b where
a.account_id=b.account_id and
a.auto='Y' and b.status=55;
```

check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wErgQqhTvLRo4JFi81YX4V/0